# How to include a webpack chunk in a static html file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, require

I have webpack building all my individual JS components into a bundle components.bundle.js

An example of a component:

```
export class Comp1 {
  test() {
    console.log('worked');
  }
};
```

I then have a static html page that includes my components.bundle.js but I don't know how I can then use the components as I thought I could just do something like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./components.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var comp1 = new Comp1();

        comp1.test();
    </script>
</body>
```

But this does not work, what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I meant: <script type="text/javascript" src="./components.bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Comment: What error(s) are you getting with this approach?

Answer (score 0):

When you have run webpack and got the bundle.js you can simply add this as a script like so:

```
<script src="path/to/my/bundle.js"></script>
```

All the operations you would like to perform (like making an instance of such a class and accessing its members) and any other logic you would like to incorporate into your project should be written the same way you have done in the code example you have provided, that is, it should be kept away from the actual HTML that will include the `bundle.js`. You could achieve this by creating more files that will hold and reference other logic you have written.

The main point is, it is not recommended to handle business logic inside a layout page.

For instance:

**Incorrect to write**

```
export class Comp1 {
  test() {
    console.log('worked');
  }
};
```

**And access like this**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./components.bundle.js" 
    charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      var comp1 = new Comp1();
      comp1.test();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Correct to write**

```
  export class Comp1 {
    test() {
      console.log('worked');
    }
  };
```

**And access like this (most probably in another `.js` file, say `main.js`)**

```
var comp1 = require('path/to/my/component')

comp1.test()
```

The take-away point here is that your code must be self-contained; functional (working) on its own (without needing the HTML), it must perform all the tasks it needs to without having being injected into anything. Injecting to the HTML file should only serve to serve this logic in the browser, in most cases, to be able to visually see its effects.

Comment: Yeah, i've included the bundle, but how can I access the classes and export functions that are defined? because when i look in the file it's wrapped in webpackJsonp() function...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Everything is bundled into components.bundle.js so how can i then do 'require('path/to/my/component')', when that file doesn't exist and the source code is out of the www folder anyway.

Comment: What do you mean the file does not exist?

You would have, as an example, two files, one `main.js` the other `comp1.js`. Inside `main.js` you `require('path/to/comp1')` and use it inside `main.js`

Comment: All the Javascript is bundled into components.bundle.js - I then have a static HTML file where some of the components that have been bundled need to initialised (I know I can include them from another JS file, but unfortunately it has to be from an html file). So I thought this should work, but it doesn't?    <script>
      var comp1 = new Comp1();
      comp1.test();
    </script>

Comment: The components do NOT have to be initialised inside the HTML file. They can be initialised in the same or any other `.js` file. Why would you want to initialise them in an HTML file?

Comment: Yes I know. But due to limitations (AEM/CMS implementation) the components need to be initialized from inside a HTML - this is my problem and my question. When I include the components.bundle.js in that HTML how can I then access the individual exported components?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160250/discussion-between-brandnew-and-ben-southall).